# Gerar arquivo com JS

Tags: javascript

Tenho uma consulta e monto uma string com o resultado. Até ai já tá tudo ok!

O que está me dando trabalho é encontrar uma boa forma para que quando a consulta termine e a string já esteja montada, um arquivo contendo a string seja baixado para o pc do cliente.

Comment: Talvez isso te ajude, se souber inglês no caso: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749231/download-file-using-javascript-jquery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode definir um elemento de âncora, `<a>`, utilizando a codificação da URL para gerar seu arquivo TXT e baixá-lo. Basta você criar dinamicamente o elemento, definir o atributo `href` e a propriedade `download` com o nome do arquivo que deseja criar; após você insere no corpo da página - alguns navegadores podem bloquear o evento `click` se o elemento não estiver no corpo da página - e disparar o evento `click` do elemento, removendo-o do corpo da página ao final.

```
function createAndDownload(filename, text) {
  const element = document.createElement('a');

  element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
  element.setAttribute('download', filename);

  element.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(element);

  element.click();

  document.body.removeChild(element);
}
```

Veja um exemplo:

```js
function createAndDownload(filename, text) {
  const element = document.createElement('a');

  element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
  element.setAttribute('download', filename);

  element.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(element);

  element.click();

  document.body.removeChild(element);
}
```

```html
<button onClick="createAndDownload('sopt.txt', 'Stack Overflow em Português')">Download</button>
```

Comment: Só pra constar display=none com click as vezes não rola (depende do navegador+dispositivo), inclusive eu propus uma solução com setTimeout e mais algumas coisas por compatibilidade e uma série de testes: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/217960/3635

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento saberia dizer em qual não funciona? Lembro que quando escrevi a resposta a única *limitação* era que precisava adicionar ao DOM a âncora para poder executar o *click*.

Comment: É uma coisa que varia de versão para versão, que provavelmente hoje a maioria já se adequa bem a solução mais simples, ainda sim sempre sou sismado com devices, como mobiles (claro que iOS é o unico que não tem suporte a isso, não sei como esta no iOS12Preview), no iOS11 preciso testar com calma, hoje tem o app nativo "Files", mas não sei se ele interage com o Safari. Prometo testar com calma e lhe devolver um feedback :)